# Why does maps.google.co.uk show me the web search page?

Tags: google-search, google-maps

Since moving to the UK I have a weird problem on Google Maps: It always shows me the Google web search interface rather than a map. For example, https://maps.google.co.uk/m?q=london&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&gbv=1&ie=UTF-8&oi=nojs looks like this:

[image: Google web search for "London"]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue is a simple bit of miscommunication: I am using [NoScript](http://noscript.net/)*, and I have allowed google.com, but not google.co.uk. Since **Google automatically redirects anyone in the UK to .co.uk addresses**, and **silently show their web search page rather than informing users that maps won't work without JavaScript**, this was the result.

Fix: Allow google.co.uk in NoScript.

* To force most web sites into loading in a reasonable time and with as little bleep as possible.